# Redirecting All Subdirectories to Single Location

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I am using `.htaccess` to rewrite my subdirectories or additional URL information in links to a single location. I'm not quite sure how to phrase this, so I'll include examples below.

**`OLD URL                                                  NEW URL`**
`oldsite.com/shop                                newsite.com/shop`
`oldsite.com/shop/something                      newsite.com/shop`
`oldsite.com/shop/category/product/123.html      newsite.com/shop`
`oldsite.com/shop/landingpage                    newsite.com/shop`

There are still a number of additional functions that oldsite is performing, so I only want the `/shop` (and anything after that) to redirect to the newsite.

If it would be easier to do this somewhere besides `.htaccess` that would be great too.

Answer (score 2):

That can easily be done with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shop https://newsite.com/shop [R=301,L]
```

This will look at the URL and, if it begins with "shop" (the leading / is ignored automatically), redirect to the new URL.
Note that it will also redirect /shopping. If that is not what you want, you'd have to modifiy the pattern.

It will use a `301 Moved Permanently` HTTP status code, but you could change that to another 3XX code by modifying the R flag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me so quickly!  When I tried this for oldsite.com/shop/product123 it takes me to newsite.com/shopproduct123 instead of just newsite.com/shop

Comment: That's odd, it shouldn't (and I've just tested it to make sure I'm not misremembering it). Do you have anything similar to "redirect permanent /shop http://newsite.com/shop" in your .htaccess? Because those will add trailing characters, while RewriteRule won't, unless you explicitly say so (by using a `(...)` group and `$1` in the redirect URL).

Comment: @rukristin Also make sure you've cleared your browser cache. If you've previously experimented with (erroneous?) 301s then these will have been cached by the browser. It's often easier to test with 302 (temporary) redirects for this reason (that are not cached by the browser).